# Transferring all of a cairo RecordingSurface to SVG

Tags: python-3.x, svg, cairo

With the following code, I am attempting to draw a graph with cairocffi. Since I won't know how big the graph is until I draw it, I'm using an unbounded RecordingSurface to record the operations, and then transferring the operations to an SVGSurface of the correct dimensions. However, when I do this, only a small part of the graph appears in the upper left corner of the outputted image. (The particular graph I did this with ends up mostly with negative x and y coordinates.) How do I get the whole graph to show up in the final SVGSurface?

```
import cairocffi as cairo
# ...
def draw_line(ctx):
    dx, dy = unit_vector(ctx.angle)
    ctx.rel_line_to(dx, dy)

def eval_symbol(sym, ctx):
    if sym == 'L':
        ctx.angle -= ANGLE
    elif sym == 'R':
        ctx.angle += ANGLE
    elif sym == 'F':
        draw_line(ctx)

def graph(iteration):
    rec_surf = cairo.RecordingSurface(cairo.CONTENT_COLOR, None)
    ctx = cairo.Context(rec_surf)
    ctx.move_to(0, 0)
    ctx.angle = 0

    for sym in iteration:
        eval_symbol(sym, ctx)
    ctx.stroke()
    x, y, width, height = rec_surf.ink_extents()
    print(x, y, width, height)

    final_surf = cairo.SVGSurface(FILENAME, width, height)
    final_ctx = cairo.Context(final_surf)
    final_ctx.set_source_surface(rec_surf, 0, 0)
    final_ctx.paint()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly replayed (painted) a recording surface to an svg surface by setting it as the source surface.

However, you have failed to account for the x/y offset in the ink extents.

All the data were output to svg. You are simply not be seeing it because your image viewer is clipping the output to the size of the svg view-port.

When you set the source surface, set the offset as well to put all the inked surface inside the viewport. (Note that it must be -x,-y)

You can open the svg in Inkscape to see beyond the view-port.

```
#!/bin/python3

import cairo

def draw(surface, S):
    cr = cairo.Context(surface)
    cr.set_source_rgba(1, 0, 0, 1)
    cr.rectangle(0, 0, S, S)
    cr.stroke()
    
    # draw something partially outside of the target surface svg window
    cr.set_source_rgba(0, 1, 0, 1)
    cr.rectangle(-10, -10, 20, 20)
    cr.fill()
    
    # draw something entirely outside of the target surface svg window
    cr.set_source_rgba(0, 1, 0, 1)
    cr.rectangle(-100, -100, 20, 20)
    cr.fill()

    
if __name__=='__main__':
    S = 100

    rec = cairo.RecordingSurface(cairo.CONTENT_COLOR, None)
    
    #draw
    draw(rec, S)

    #replay
    x, y, width, height = rec.ink_extents()
    print(x, y, width, height)
    svg = cairo.SVGSurface("out.svg", width, height)
    
    cr = cairo.Context(svg)
    cr.set_source_surface(rec, -x, -y)
    cr.paint()

    svg.finish()
    svg.flush()
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="201pt" height="201pt" viewBox="0 0 201 201" version="1.1">
<defs>
<g id="surface7" clip-path="url(#clip1)">
<rect width="16777215" height="16777215" style="opacity:1;stroke:none;fill:rgb(0,0,0);"/>
<path style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(100%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M 0 0 L 100 0 L 100 100 L 0 100 Z M 0 0 " transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-0,0)"/>
<path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,100%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M -10 -10 L 10 -10 L 10 10 L -10 10 Z M -10 -10 "/>
<path style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,100%,0%);fill-opacity:1;" d="M -100 -100 L -80 -100 L -80 -80 L -100 -80 Z M -100 -100 "/>
</g>
</defs>
<g id="surface4">
<use xlink:href="#surface7" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,100,100)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```